# Python face_recognition and saving file with cv2

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, opencv, multiprocessing, face-recognition

This is my first time posting a question so pardon any mistakes. I'm trying to write a script that will do face_recognition and save the video file at the same time and running into I think latency issues. When there isn't a face to detect it saves the video file fine. When there is a face though it seems to get every other frame.  I feel like that is because it's doing computations for finding the face which prevents it from saving the next frame.  Is there a way around this? maybe threading or multiprocessing?

```
import face_recognition as fr
import os
import face_recognition
import numpy as np
import cv2
def get_encoded_faces():
    encoded = {}
    for dirpath, dnames, fnames in os.walk("./faces"):
        for f in fnames:
            if f.endswith(".jpg") or f.endswith(".png"):
                face = fr.load_image_file("faces/" + f)
                encoding = fr.face_encodings(face)[0]
                encoded[f.split(".")[0]] = encoding

    return encoded
def unknown_image_encoded(img):
    face = fr.load_image_file("faces/" + img)
    encoding = fr.face_encodings(face)[0]
    return encoding
faces = get_encoded_faces()
faces_encoded = list(faces.values())
known_face_names = list(faces.keys())
def FindFace(img):
    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(img)
    unknown_face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(img, face_locations)
    face_names = []
    for face_encoding in unknown_face_encodings:
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(faces_encoded, face_encoding)
        name = "Unknown"
        face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(faces_encoded, face_encoding)
        best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
        if matches[best_match_index]:
            name = known_face_names[best_match_index]
        face_names.append(name)
        #cv2.imwrite('final_image.png',img)
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'), 20.0, (640,480))
if not video_capture.isOpened():
    raise Exception("Could not open video device")
while(video_capture.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    out.write(frame)
    #cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
    FindFace(frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```